# iOS App registered for open file extension missing in Gdrive Open in

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-drive-api, ios8.3

I registered my application to open a file with custom extension(app highlighted in red rectangle). It was worked well in Google drive application and other all other applications like mail and etc.

[image]

After updated the latest Google drive application it was not working in google drive app only but working in other applications.

[image]

Also checked with "open in" button, my application missing. We are using google drive for file sharing with particular file extension. It was worked earlier but dosn't working any more.

I tried the same in Safari with drive.google.com.

[image]

This is how i registered a file extension to open in my app

[image]

Please help me to fix this issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is your application is still shown as an option in the web interface?

Comment: @Eric I tried in web interface (Safari), now i added the web interface image also in my post please refer. Files not downloading but it's showing my app name  and when i click Open in "Tiltsta" nothing happen.

Comment: Is your application a [Drive app](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/listing)? Or is it just a regular iOS app? Can you show how you registered the file extension?

Comment: @Eric this is regular ios app. Now i added a image for how i registered the file extension, please refer.